# how to display and edit mvc ApplicationUser Properties

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am wanting to display and edit a ApplicationUser with AngularJS and webapi. The ApplicationUser model has the default properties, IdentityRole and a many to many relationship with a Company class. I would like to be able to use a form with checkboxes to display edit each user. something like this

I made a plunker with the JSON from ApplicationUser, ApplicationRoles and Companies [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLwzUle2tC2h84lwIXaK?p=preview)

```
 Full Name : <input ng-model="FullName" type="text"/>
 Email : <input ng-model="Email" type="text"/>
 Role : 
       <ul ng-repeat="r in roles">
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="RoleId" /> {{RoleName}} 
          </li>
       </ul>
  Company(s) : 
       <ul ng-repeat="c in companies">
         <li>
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="CompanyID" /> {{CompanyName}}
         </li>
      </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Angular Controller

```
 ApplicationUser.query(function (data) {
            $scope.applicationUsers = data;
        });//



        //get single ApplicationUser
        $scope.editApplicationUser = function (id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({ method: 'get', url: '/api/ApplicationUsers/' + id })
                    .success(function (model) {
                        deferred.resolve(model);
                        $scope.model = model;
                    }).error(function (error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    }).then(function () {
                        $modal.open({
                            templateUrl: "EditApplicationUserModal.html",
                            controller: "ModalInstanceController",
                            //size: 'lg',
                            resolve: {
                                model: function () {
                                    return $scope.model;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    })
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        //update applicationUsers
        $scope.updateApplicationUser = function (model) {
            model = $scope.model;
            ApplicationUserUpdate.update(model).success(function (model) {

                $scope.close();
            }).error(function (err, result) {
                console.log(err, result);
            });
        };
```

Identity Model

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }


    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Companies = new List<Company>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
       // Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(up => up.Companies)
            .WithMany(company => company.ApplicationUsers)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.ToTable("T_ApplicationUser_Company");
                mc.MapLeftKey("Id");
                mc.MapRightKey("CompanyID");
            }
        );

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Company Model

```
 public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your angular controller look like?

Comment: i updated my post. I haven't done much in the angular controller yet. I wasn't sure how to approach this. I went ahead and posted my models as well. ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole and Company have the default webapi entity framework scaffolded controllers.

Comment: I was thinking after I created the user I could grab the ApplicationUser Id and post to the Roles, and ApplicationUser_Company linking tables. Ive never worked with many to many relationships before. If there is a better way then please let me know.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading the question right, but I don't get which bit you are having an issue with.

Comment: i think i overloaded it with too much information. If I could get the plunker to work that would be great. Basically after I register a user, email and password only. I will select them from a table. thats where the plunker comes in. I will add there FullName, Edit Email if need be, assign the Role Type and assign a company or companys. So in the plunker I need to have all of the different RoleTypes displayed with check boxes and the same for the companies. If I can get that done then I can move on to the next step

Comment: You have some spelling mistakes, which is why the company list is not showing, and the role names are not showing.  For company: `<ul ng-repeat="c in companys">` and `<li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="CompanyID" /> {{c.CompanyName}}</li>`.  For roles: `<li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="RoleId" /> {{r.Name}}</li>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that the companies are not being listed at all, is because the `ng-repeat` is referencing `companies` where your scope has `companys`.

This is what you need:

```
<ul ng-repeat="c in companys">
   <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="CompanyID" /> {{c.CompanyName}}</li><br/><br/>
</ul>
```

The role names are not being displayed, because the internal `r` variable on the `ng-repeat` was not being used.  Needs to be:

```
<ul ng-repeat="r in roles">
   <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="RoleId" /> {{r.Name}}</li><br/><br/>
</ul>
```